# iOS SceneKit: TextNode following the camera

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a few SCNText node, described as follows:

```
let newText = SCNText(string: "", extrusionDepth:0.1)
    newText.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    newText.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 3)
    textNode = SCNNode(geometry: newText)
    self.addChildNode(textNode)
```

How to make so that the text is always looking at the camera?

Answer (score 2):

textNode.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]